# Is $|(v,\frac{Pv}{||Pv||})|=||Pv||$ when $P$ is an orthogonal projection?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces, inner-products

Suppose $P$ is an  $k \times k$ matrix that represents an orthogonal projection.  Let $v$ be an $k \times 1$ vector. Let the operator $(\cdot,\cdot)$ represents the scalar product.

Does this equality holds $|(v,\frac{Pv}{||Pv||})|=||Pv||$ ? if so, how to prove it ? else, is there any condition under which this equality is correct ?

Comment: Projection is an endomorphism.  Meaning it can only be represented by square matrices.

Comment: @Bye_World Do you think that completing the matrix by zero columns makes sense ?

Comment: As for your question, does this help? $$(v,Pv) = (Pv+Rv,Pv) = (Pv,Pv)+(Rv,Pv) = \|Pv\|^2$$  where $Rv$ is a *rejection* (i.e. a vector orthogonal to $Pv$).

Comment: Sure it does help! Plz put this as an answer so that we can get some feedback on, and so that I can accept it.

Comment: Your answer is independent from the fact that $P$ is an orthogonal projection? if no, could you plz tell me if completing $P$ by zero columns (so that $P$ becomes square matrix) has any impact on the answer. Thx!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you can always decompose a vector into a non-orthogonal projection and a vector orthogonal to it -- I've never tried to prove that.  You can if you like.  The matrix $P$ doesn't represent a projection if it is not square.  Completing it with zero columns is probably what you want to do to make it into the matrix representing the projection you're talking about -- but I'd have to see the matrix to be sure.  But here's how you can check for yourself if a matrix represents a projection:  $(1)$ it's square, $(2)$ it satisfies $P^2=P$, and $(3)$ it's Hermitian.

Comment: @Bye_World One final question if possible. Do you know the answer for $|(v^*,\frac{Pv}{||P^*v ||})|^2$, where $(\cdot)^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$(v,Pv) = (Pv+Rv,Pv) = (Pv,Pv)+(Rv,Pv) = \|Pv\|^2$$

where $Rv$ is a *rejection* (i.e. a vector orthogonal to $Pv$).